# Getting exception org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 9100: starting in 0.20.2 version of hadoop

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin

I'm getting exception while setting HDFS environment(Using cygwin on windows7). I am able to access 1. NameNode - {http://localhost:50070/} and 2.JobTracker - {http://localhost:50030/} but I am getting exception:

Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException     and also getting

2012-07-05 18:43:34,726 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 9100, call addBlock(/home/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info, DFSClient_1001718281) from 127.0.0.1:51303: error: java.io.IOException: File /home/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
java.io.IOException: File /home/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1)

Please help me to resolve the issue.

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>                           
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

mapredsite.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
                 <value>localhost:9001</value>
             </property>
        </configuration>
```

Core-Site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property> 
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
<!--<value>/home/hadoop/tmp</value> -->
<value>/cygwin/home/syadav</value>
</property>
 <property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 </property>
 <property> 
 <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
<value>1</value>
<description>define ma p red.map tasks to be number of slave hosts</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
<value>1</value>
<description>define ma p red.red uce tasks to be number of slave hosts</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Let me know what other details you are looking for. I have already told error which I'm getting in logs.

Comment: It could be because of many reasons. Without the proper exception and more details it's difficult to resolve the problem - have you checked this article? http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html

Comment: @Praveen  I have updated original problem with more details. Let me know if any thing else is required. I already tried the link you provided.

Comment: Can you confirm the Name Node shows that the Data Node is up and running, if not go and look at the data node logs to see why it isn't starting.

Comment: @Chris On running JPS, I can see that only NameNode and JobTracker are up and running. I can access url {http://localhost:50070/} and {http://localhost:50030/}.In JobTracker log file logs are like "Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null". Can you tell me reason for this ?

Comment: You'll need to open the log files for the datanode - find you hadoop log folder and look for a file named `*datanode*.log`

Comment: Ya looking into C:\Hadoop\hadoop-0.20.2\logs folder only. No log file created for datanode. I can see only *namenode*.log and *jobtracker*.log . Did I missed something?

Comment: Now I am getting following error                                                 hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/intraedgepune/syadav/PiEstimator_TMP_3_141592654/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1                                                                    Any Idea how to resolve it?